# SQLAlchemy Core Connection Context Manager

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

Can I use a context manager for SQLAlchemy Core connections? In other words, is

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute('SELECT * FROM FOO')
conn.close()
```

the same as

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute('SELECT * FROM FOO')
```

I don't need any checks for commits, rollbacks, etc at context manager exit.

Answer (score 30):

You can use a connection as context manager.

See the connections's [`__enter__`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/cec89cae156903c9a77dff29a1213e70fa915b52/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py?at=master#cl-107) and [`__exit__`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/cec89cae156903c9a77dff29a1213e70fa915b52/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py?at=master#cl-110) methods for how this is implemented. `__enter__` just returns `self` and `__exit__` calls close.

Or you could just try it:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
with engine.connect() as conn:
    print(conn.closed)
print(conn.closed)
```

output:

```
False
True
```